# Overriding default error messages in email input widget in django

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I am trying to override the default invalid email error message in Django. As the Django Doc says, the following code should work, but it's not. How can I adjust it?

```
class BootstrapAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):
forms.Form.error_css_class = 'error'
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254,
                            error_messages={'required': 'Please enter a valid email address.',
                                            'invalid': 'Please enter a valid email address.'},
                           widget=forms.EmailInput({
                               'required': True,
                               'class': 'form-control', 
                               'placeholder': 'E-mail address',
                               }))
```

And, the error_css_class is not working properly: there is no change at all. What's wrong with this setting?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a mistake here: `widget=forms.EmailInput({..})` it should be `widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={...})`

Comment: The widget is rendering properly, so it's fine. The problem is the error messages are not overriding the default messages.

Comment: well, I have tested myself, and yes its not working properly, and for Charfield it did not work a few times, I am not sure about that, could be my browser's caching problem. Anyways, I will suggest you to use either JS or forms clean method for workaround.

Comment: I have changed to the attrs, but it's not rendering as I meant. It's rendering in the template (html) properly, so the error messages are bounding(?) well to EmailField. But I want to override the error messages coming from EmailInput - the inline popup error messsage. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use EmailValidator:

```
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, validators=[EmailValidator(message="Your message")]
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, this works fine if I wanted to render the custom error messages in a template (html) as field.errors. The question is how to override the default error messages coming from the EmailInput widget, i.e. the inline popup error message. Thanks.